# Mangling column names in MSSQL for security

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I recently joined a new project where the previous product manager decided to mangle column names in a majority of the tables, from what I hear this was aimed at security/protection of our code since a major part is SQL Stored Procedures.

Here's a simple visualization:

```
+-----------+------------+----+----------+-------+
| C1        | C2         | C3 | C4       | C5    |
+-----------+------------+----+----------+-------+
| John Doe  | 11-11-1944 | M  | Street 1 | Julie |
+-----------+------------+----+----------+-------+
| Mary Jane | 13-02-1991 | F  | Street 2 | null  |
+-----------+------------+----+----------+-------+
```

Somewhere I agree with him that we need to mangle the names, but not when we are developing rather before delivering the product to the customer. The application itself is in .NET C#.

**First, how can I recover from this? Any strategy or preferably a tool (similar to the lines of uglify for JS)?**

**Second, how can I still protect the code (Stored Procedure) after unmangling the names?**

Comment: I'm afraid I don't agree... There's no good reason to do this. Anyone with access to the database could work it out given a little time but it makes debugging/developing a lot harder. Use the appropriate security features of the Database to limit what a user can do. Encrypt communications to avoid packet sniffing, etc...

Comment: Oy, you should never uglify your database.  That's crazy.  If you're not following best practices in your database, it doesn't matter what you name your columns, someone's still going to get access to your data.  And by doing this, what he's done is made the lives of the developers more difficult as nothing has a logical name.  The database names should be logical, they should be make sense, and they should be clear what they pertain to, regardless of whether you're using stored procedures.

Comment: Have a +1 for braveness working with a system like that.  It sounds to me like it would be easier to find work somewhere else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have no idea why anyone would think that mangling names would make the system more secure.  If you want security, then use the database security features.  For instance, don't allow anyone to read the tables directly, require that stored procedures be used.  Or, encrypt the data itself, so that doesn't get read.  Normally, it is the data that is secure, not the names of the columns.

That said, I don't see how you can get away from the "mangled" names during development.  You *could* use views that map the mangled names to unmangled names.  However, that just means that you have a bunch of code that needs to be changed when the database structure changes.  Worse, it means that the original developers will be very confused when they are trying to solve problems after release.

Comment: The link shared by @Lee Willis helps too.

Answer (score 3):

With Mangling ... do you mean giving meaningful names to columns? If yes, then you can create a different table with same schema definition as of your posted table then just do a

```
insert into your_new_table
select c1,c2,c3,c4,c5 from 
your_mangled_table
```

> how can I still protect the code (Stored Procedure) after unmangling
>   the names

That's won't be possible automatically. You will have to `ALTER` your procedure code to modify the column/table name(s) to reflect the new changes.

Answer (score 2):

SQL server supports stored procedure encryption. I have never used it so can't comment further but this may help you. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187926.aspx